# Copying using a file list

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of filenames without their extension and a folder and sub-folders of those files with their extensions. I am trying to use the list to copy those files to a different location. I tried to use a script I found here and modified it:

```bat
@echo off
FOR /R "P:\Case\MyCase\Productions" %%G in (.) do (
  for /F "delims=" %%i in (UniqueFileList.txt) do (
    if exist %%G\%%i.* xcopy %%G\%%i.* "C:\Temp\CopiedFiles" /D /Y
  )
)
```

My file names are TIN00001.msg, TIN00002.txt, TIN00003.jpg, etc...

and the names in my file list is TIN00001, TIN00002, TIN00003, etc...

How can I use a script to copy the files ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks !!

Mustu

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your intention but my best guess is that something like this would suit you.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "rootDir=P:\Case\MyCase\Productions"
Set "destDir=C:\Temp\CopiedFiles"
Set "listTxt=%~dp0UniqueFileList.txt"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where/R "%rootDir%" *.*^|FindStr/LIG:"%listTxt%"'
) Do FindStr/LIX "%%~nA" "%listTxt%">Nul 2>&1 && XCopy "%%A" "%dstDir%" /D /Y
```

*If `%listTxt%` isn't in the same location as the script then change it's location to a full path too.*

Comment: thank you for the script. I tried it and modified it to match my folder:

Comment: @Echo Off
Set "rootDir=G:\Vertex01"
Set "destDir=C:\Temp\Search05"
Set "listTxt=%~dp0Search05.txt"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where/R "%rootDir%" *.*^|FindStr/LIG:"%listTxt%"'
) Do FindStr/LIX "%%~nA" "%listTxt%">Nul 2>&1 && XCopy "%%A" "%dstDir%" /D /Y

Comment: and it says "Invalid drive specification", "0 files copied"

Comment: I have moved the folder to my C:\Temp folder and am still getting that error. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: This message shows that my script works, what is failing is the XCopy command with your provided paths. I'm guessing that G: is a network mapped drive as there tend to be many issues with XCopy and mapped drives. If it is then try putting the UNC name instead `Set "rootDir=\\netpcname\vertex01"`. If not try replacing XCopy for Copy to see if that works instead, especially if you don't really need it's **`/D`** option.

Comment: Thank you @Compo!! there was a typo. Once I fixed that, it worked like a charm! Thanks again for your help, this is going to be a big help for me!